# Unity PixelPerfectCamera UpscaleRenderTexture problem

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, 2d

Hello I enabled the Upscale Render Texture Parameter for the Pixel Perfect Camera in Unity and set the Pixels Per Unit to 16 Reference Resolution 180 X 320 and then set the game resolution to 1640 X 2360, the ViewPortRect is assigned a value other than 1 and the Canvas image is An afterimage remains when passing the edge of the screen. I would like to know what could be the cause and how to fix it.
[gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vabki.gif)

I want to enable the Upscale Render Texture and have the ViewPort Rect come out as 0,0,1,1